# Custom listview vertical line doesn't show up

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

Everything else except the vertical line is visible. Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/verses_custom_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.ad.holyquran.extra.TextViewEx
    android:id="@+id/textView_Verse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_VerseTranslation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Verse"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/versesRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/versesImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_verse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_verseNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/versesImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="280"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff008328"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/versesImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It however shows up in design view of the XML, check link below, but it won't show on my actual (GS3-I9300) device.
http://i60.tinypic.com/jz9kpf.jpg

Comment: can you please send us snap shot what you are getting on your real device?

Comment: I get everything except that vertical line.

Comment: DOn't know what issue in your system i pasted same code and it shown me that Green vertical line perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

-Hello here is the snapshot i pasted same code of yours and i got this screen.[image]
-See the green vertical line.

Comment: Thanks, I also get that in design view but when i run it on actual device the vertical line is gone while the rest is there.

Comment: Hello even i get same output at run time also. please try changing color and width of your verticle line and check it again.